# Getting Mouse click coordinates on CLR application which uses CefSharp Nuget Package

Tags: mfc, clr, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I want to **get the coordinates of the place where user clicks on a page**.Basically I want the **mouse event on the ChromiumWebBrowser page**.

I am building an MFC MDI CView derived browser app which uses a reference to CLR. To do this I followed the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBvDK6LE4XM.

I am using nuget packages cef.redist.x86(3.3325.1758),cef.redist.x64(3.3325.1758),CefSharp.Common(65.0.0-pre01),CefSharp.WinForms(65.0.0-pre01).

The implementation has a toolstripcontainer and I am loading my browser as follows:

```
ChromiumWebBrowser^ browser;
browser= gcnew ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser->Load("http://google.com");
this->CefToolStripContainer->ContentPanel->Controls->Add(browser);
browser->Dock = DockStyle::Fill;
this->AddressToolStripTextBox->Text = "http://google.com";
```

I am able to get the events like OnFrameLoadEnd. But when I try to get event of the mouse click nothing happens when I do this

```
this->browser->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &clr_cefbrowser::CefBrowserCtrl::OnClick);
```

The click event is fired for other controls that I add(after removing browser from contentpanel),but not for browser.
Below is the complete code for the implementation.

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

using namespace CefSharp;
using namespace CefSharp::WinForms;
using namespace System::Threading::Tasks;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

#include <vector>


namespace clr_cefbrowser {

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for CefBrowserCtrl
    /// </summary>
    public ref class CefBrowserCtrl : public System::Windows::Forms::UserControl
    {
    public:
        CefBrowserCtrl(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }

    private:
        ChromiumWebBrowser^ browser;

    public:
        void InitBrowser()
        {
            browser = gcnew ChromiumWebBrowser();
            browser->Load("http://google.com");
            this->CefToolStripContainer->ContentPanel
                ->Controls->Add(browser);
            browser->Dock = DockStyle::Fill;
            this->AddressToolStripTextBox->Text = "http://google.com";
            this->browser->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, 
                                                           &clr_cefbrowser::CefBrowserCtrl::OnClick);
        }

    protected:
        ~CefBrowserCtrl()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripContainer^  CefToolStripContainer;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip^  CefToolStrip;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripLabel^  toolStripLabel1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripTextBox^  AddressToolStripTextBox;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton^  GoToolStripButton;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

   #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
   void InitializeComponent(void)
   {
      System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew 
      System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(CefBrowserCtrl::typeid));
      this->CefToolStripContainer = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripContainer());
      this->CefToolStrip = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip());
      this->toolStripLabel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripLabel());
      this->AddressToolStripTextBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripTextBox());
      this->GoToolStripButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton());
      this->CefToolStripContainer->TopToolStripPanel->SuspendLayout();
      this->CefToolStripContainer->SuspendLayout();
      this->CefToolStrip->SuspendLayout();
      this->SuspendLayout();
      // 
      // CefToolStripContainer
      // 
      // 
      // CefToolStripContainer.ContentPanel
      // 
      this->CefToolStripContainer->ContentPanel->Size = System::Drawing::Size(476, 265);
      this->CefToolStripContainer->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
      this->CefToolStripContainer->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
      this->CefToolStripContainer->Name = L"CefToolStripContainer";
      this->CefToolStripContainer->Size = System::Drawing::Size(476, 290);
      this->CefToolStripContainer->TabIndex = 0;
      this->CefToolStripContainer->Text = L"toolStripContainer1";
      // 
      // CefToolStripContainer.TopToolStripPanel
      // 
      this->CefToolStripContainer->TopToolStripPanel->Controls->Add(this->CefToolStrip);
     // 
     // CefToolStrip
     // 
     this->CefToolStrip->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::None;
     this->CefToolStrip->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(3) {
    this->toolStripLabel1,
        this->AddressToolStripTextBox, this->GoToolStripButton
    });
    this->CefToolStrip->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 0);
    this->CefToolStrip->Name = L"CefToolStrip";
    this->CefToolStrip->Size = System::Drawing::Size(337, 25);
    this->CefToolStrip->TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // toolStripLabel1
    // 
    this->toolStripLabel1->Name = L"toolStripLabel1";
    this->toolStripLabel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(31, 22);
    this->toolStripLabel1->Text = L"URL:";
    // 
    // AddressToolStripTextBox
    // 
    this->AddressToolStripTextBox->Name = L"AddressToolStripTextBox";
    this->AddressToolStripTextBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(250, 25);
    // 
    // GoToolStripButton
    // 
    this->GoToolStripButton->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources- 
    >GetObject(L"GoToolStripButton.Image")));
    this->GoToolStripButton->ImageTransparentColor = System::Drawing::Color::Magenta;
    this->GoToolStripButton->Name = L"GoToolStripButton";
    this->GoToolStripButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(42, 22);
    this->GoToolStripButton->Text = L"Go";
    this->GoToolStripButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, 
    &CefBrowserCtrl::GoToolStripButton_Click);
    // 
    // CefBrowserCtrl
    // 
    this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(7, 12);
    this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
    this->Controls->Add(this->CefToolStripContainer);
    this->DoubleBuffered = true;
    this->Name = L"CefBrowserCtrl";
    this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(476, 290);
    this->CefToolStripContainer->TopToolStripPanel->ResumeLayout(false);
    this->CefToolStripContainer->TopToolStripPanel->PerformLayout();
    this->CefToolStripContainer->ResumeLayout(false);
    this->CefToolStripContainer->PerformLayout();
    this->CefToolStrip->ResumeLayout(false);
    this->CefToolStrip->PerformLayout();
    this->ResumeLayout(false);
```

}

```
#pragma endregion
  public:
    ClrChromiumWebBrowser^ GetBrowser()
    {
        return this->browser;
    }
    
  private:          
    void OnClick(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^e);
```

};
}

```
void clr_cefbrowser::CefBrowserCtrl::OnClick(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^e)
{
    MessageBox::Show("Click Event");
}
```

And in My View class I have

```
CWinFormsControl<clr_cefbrowser::CefBrowserCtrl> m_CefBrowser;
```

And I get frameloadend event by using BEGIN_DELEGATE_MAP and MAKE_DELEGATE.
I am really not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: `Chromium` handles/swallows all mouse events so there is no mouse event support. What exactly do you want to do with the mouse click? Often it's easier to inject some javascript. Version 65.0.0-pre01 is years old and not supported.

Comment: Hi amaitland,I have a globe(cesium) that is loaded on the page.user should be able to add an item on the globe like a station(or any object) for that he needs the coordinate.The coordinates are fetched when user clicks a specific area on globe(on any place he wishes).How should I approach this problem?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent for injecting JavaScript to obtain a basic click.  You will nedd to upgrade to a supported version to use this method. Otherwise you'll have to hook the low level hwnd to get messages, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/84/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L272 for a rough example.

Comment: Hi amaitland,I am able to pass message to my form,but when I use https://cesium.com/cesiumjs/cesium-viewer/index.html?..I dont get any clicks.Also when i try to load this from my winform the browser hangs.Can you help me with this.

Comment: I'd suggest using JavaScript,  that's my preferred choice.

Comment: Hi @amaitland ! Sorry for the late comment. But I have come across another problem. My application loads COM dlls and when I use wait in EvaluateScriptAsync,it never returns and shows a message box saying the "Server might be busy" with buttons "Switch to", "Retry" and "Cancel". What I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Please ask a new question.